# Can I move windows 8.1 from one SSD to another without reinstall

Tags: windows-8.1, ssd

I'm planning to upgrade my SSD to a bigger one from the same manufacturer probably. Different series though. Can I move OS (win 8.1 in my case) to a new one without reinstalling? They all use some unified driver or the system will handle the change somehow?

Comment: Read up on WinPE and DISM. WinPE allows you to boot to CD and DISM allows you to capture (backup) your existing Win 8 (in its entirity) to USB and then deploy it to your new disk. It's the Microsoft recommended method.

Comment: there are several tool where you can copy current drives to new drives like EaseUS Partition Manager or this tool: http://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html

Comment: Samsung drives come with their own utility suite, one part of which does exactly what you are requesting - though I personally didn't have much luck with it & ended up using Acronis instead.